# How i set an option in dropdown list is 'selected' using beauttifulsoup in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to show text file contents in html form.There are two dropdown lists in my form,as follows.

```
<select  id="Stroke_Version" onchange="" class="input_style cylconst" name="stroke_ver">
 <option value="2S" >2S</option>
 <option value="4S" >4S</option>
</select>
<select id="engine_builder" class="input_style" name="engine_build">
 <option value="">------------Select------------</option>
 <option value="ACECNV">ACECNV (ACEC N.V)</option>
 <option value="ADRIAD">ADRIAD (Adria Diesel D.D.)</option>
</select>
```

I would like to set second option in a first dropdown list is 'selected'(which have an id 'Stroke_Version'),when displaying text file contents in corresponding input fields in html form.*How this is possible using beautifulsoup in python*.

for example:

```
<select  id="Stroke_Version" onchange="" class="input_style cylconst" name="stroke_ver">
 <option value="2S" >2S</option>
 <option value="4S" selected>4S</option>
</select>
```

Comment: might help this https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#changing-tag-names-and-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good way. Here is an example for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<select  id="Stroke_Version" onchange="" class="input_style cylconst" name="stroke_ver">
 <option value="2S" >2S</option>
 <option value="4S" >4S</option>
</select>
<select id="engine_builder" class="input_style" name="engine_build">
 <option value="">------------Select------------</option>
 <option value="ACECNV">ACECNV (ACEC N.V)</option>
 <option value="ADRIAD">ADRIAD (Adria Diesel D.D.)</option>
</select>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
option = doc.select('select#Stroke_Version').select('option@value=4S') # Get the option
index = option.outerHtml.find('>') # Get insertion location
html = doc.html[0:option._start+index]+' selected'+doc.html[option._start+index:] # Concatenate string
print (html)
```

Result:

```
<select id="Stroke_Version" onchange="" class="input_style cylconst" name="stroke_ver">
 <option value="2S">2S</option>
 <option value="4S" selected>4S</option>
</select>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `selected` attribute in the option tag which you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from your soup get option tag in which you want to add  selected using xpath or id
soup = BeautifulSoup('<option value="4S" >4S</option>')
tag = soup.option

tag["selected"] = None

print(tag)
```